# Manifest merger failed: Package name '1' at position AndroidManifest.xml:2:5-40 should contain at least one '.' (dot) character

Tags: android, flutter, build.gradle, android-manifest

```
/home/karlo/Documents/Programmin'/null/drazenrede/healthy_vibes/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml Error:
    Package name '1' at position AndroidManifest.xml:2:5-40 should contain at least one '.' (dot) character

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed: Package name '1' at position AndroidManifest.xml:2:5-40 should contain at least one '.' (dot) character
```

I got this error when trying to build a debug version of my flutter app. I figured, I'd search the internet for a solution and I found nothing.

This is the beginning of my AndroidManifest.xml, since the error says that the problem is in the beginning of the file.

```xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.example.healthy_vibes">
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the error pointed to the `line 2` in `AndroidManifest.xml` that's where I first looked for the answers.

```xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.example.healthy_vibes">
```

Soon I figured that the error was much deeper. After reading the error line `8`,

```
Manifest merger failed:
```

I figured that the problem might be in `build.gradle`. Then, I went to the `build.gradle` file.

Looking at the `build.gradle` file, under the block:

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "1"
        minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
```

I realized that this is the **applicationID** the error was talking about.
I simply changed it from `"1"` to `"com.example.healthy_vibes"` as it is in my `AndroidManifest.xml`. After doing this the error was fixed.

After fixing this, my defaultConfig looked like this:

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.healthy_vibes"
        minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
```